# Can I create  jquery mobile listview by ajax ？

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

There is the document for jquery mobile: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/about/getting-started.html

To create list view:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true">
    <li><a href="#">Acura</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Audi</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">BMW</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Cadillac</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Ferrari</a></li>
</ul>
```

But I want to create the list view by ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "../list.xml",
     dataType: "xml",
     success: function(xml) {                     
       $("#nav").append("<ul data-role='listview'' data-theme='c' data-dividertheme='d'>").find('ul').append("<li><a href='/'>test</a></li>");
      }
  });
});
```

The list element can be created, but the style is missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
$("#<id-of-your-list>").listview("refresh");
```

on your list after creating it through ajax. JQM does not automatically style dynamic content.